# Conversion of lambda expressions to Func

Tags: function, lambda, f#, func

Given the following:

```
open System.Linq

let seqA = { 1..10 }
```

this works:

```
seqA.All (fun n -> n > 0)
```

However this doesn't:

```
let abc = fun n -> n > 0

seqA.All (abc)
```

Why does F# offer implicit conversion from lambda expressions to `Func`s but not from functions? Pointers to the documentation where I can read up on what's going on here are welcome. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is covered in the (rather involved) section of the spec on [Method Resolution](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc335819028) and again in [Type-directed Conversions at Member Invocations](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc335818955). Quoting from the latter:

> As described in *Method Application Resolution* (see §14.4), two
>   type-directed conversions  are applied at method invocations.
>
> The first type-directed conversion converts anonymous function
>   expressions and other function-valued arguments to delegate types.
>   Given:
>
> - A formal parameter of delegate type *D*
> - An actual argument *farg* of known type *ty<sub>1</sub> -> ... -> ty<sub>n</sub> -> rty*
> - Precisely *n* arguments to the `Invoke` method of delegate type *D*
>
> Then:
>
> - The parameter is interpreted as if it were written:
>     `new` *D*(`fun` *arg<sub>1</sub> ... arg<sub>n</sub> -> farg arg<sub>1</sub> ... arg<sub>n</sub>*)

It seems to suggest this conversion would be applied to any function value, but observation suggests it's applied only to anonymous functions.

Comment: Sure. I just realized I left off the last part. It's fixed.

Comment: Daniel, check [this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23256355/passing-f-function-to-ienumerable-where-vs-ienumerable-all). Passing F# functions to *some* of the methods does work.