# Accepting FSharpFunc where Func is expected

Tags: .net, f#, extension-methods, func

As mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23234047/conversion-of-lambda-expressions-to-func/23234418#23234418), methods expecting a `Func` will not accept an F# function value.

What's a good approach to overloading a method such that it will accept F# function values?

Answer (score 7):

I know this is not what you're asking, but instead of directly attempting to support F# from code written in C# (as I get the impression that you're trying to do), it would be **more idiomatic** to provide a small **adapter module** to make functional composition easier from F#.

There are many examples of this, such as [FSharp.Reactive](http://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.Reactive/), which provides functions to make it easier to use [Reactive Extensions](https://rx.codeplex.com/) from F#.

For example, if you want to access [Enumerable.All](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx) from F#, you *could* write a little adapter function, e.g.

```fs
let all f (s : 'a seq) = s.All (fun x -> f x)
```

which you could then use like this:-

```
seqA |> all abc
```

However, in the case of `All`, you can use the built-in F# functions for that:

```
seqA |> Seq.forall abc
```

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't just creating a Func<*,*> be enough?

```
let doSomethingWithFunc (f : System.Func<_,_>) =
    42

let doSomethingWithFSharpFunc (f : 'a -> 'b) =
    System.Func<_,_>(f) |> doSomethingWithFunc

(fun x -> 42) |> doSomethingWithFSharpFunc
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the code from your initial question, the easiest solution is to create an instance of the expected delegate (`Func<int, bool>` in this case) and pass the function value as the argument.

```
let seqA = { 1..10 }
let abc = fun n -> n > 0
seqA.All (Func<_,_> abc)
```

Patryk noted this syntax in his comment, but I thought I'd add an explanation of what is truly happening.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach:

```
open System
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.Linq

type IEnumerable<'T> with
    member this.All(pred: 'T -> bool) = this.All(Func<_,_> pred)

let even n = n % 2 = 0

let seqA = seq { 0..2..10 }

seqA.All(even) |> printfn "%A"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of passing an F# function value to `IEnumerable.All`:

```
open System.Linq
open IEnumerableAllFSharpFunc

let seqA = seq { 1..10 }

let abc n = n > 0

seqA.All abc |> printfn "%A"
```

given this extension method on `IEnumerable.All`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.FSharp.Core;

namespace IEnumerableAllFSharpFunc
{
    public static class Utils
    {
        public static bool All<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq, FSharpFunc<T, bool> pred)
        {
            var converter = FSharpFunc<T, bool>.ToConverter(pred);

            Func<T, bool> func = (elt) => converter(elt);

            return seq.All(func);
        }
    }
}
```

More elegant approaches welcome. :-)

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek: That works, but is actually not a cast. It's equivalent to `seqA.All(new Func<_,_>(abc))`. Casts in F# take the form `x <op> 'T` where `<op>` is `:>` or `:?>`.