# module vs type behavior difference on using F# lambda as actual argument to formal parameter that expects System.Func

Tags: f#

Assume I have some library code like

```
open System

module Foo =
    let Invoke1 (action : Func<string>) = ()
    let Invoke2 (action : Func<int, string>) = ()
    let Invoke3 (key : int, add : Func<int, string>, update: Func<int, string, string>) = ()       
    let Invoke4 (key : int) (add : Func<int, string>) (update: Func<int, string, string>) = ()

type Bar =
    static member Invoke1 (action : Func<string>) = ()
    static member Invoke2 (action : Func<int, string>) = ()
    static member Invoke3 (key : int, add : Func<int, string>, update: Func<int, string, string>) = ()
    static member Invoke4 (key : int) (add : Func<int, string>) (update: Func<int, string, string>) = ()
```

Now when these methods were invoked, there're actually behavior difference

First, the following three lines do not compile

```
Foo.Invoke1(fun () -> "") 
Foo.Invoke2(fun a -> "") 
Foo.Invoke3(5, (fun k -> ""), (fun k v -> v))
```

They all have the same compilation error

```
error FS0002: This function takes too many arguments, or is used in a context where a function is not expected
```

However, the following three lines compile just fine

```
Bar.Invoke1(fun () -> "") 
Bar.Invoke2(fun a -> "")
Bar.Invoke3(5, (fun k -> ""), (fun k v -> v))
```

So somehow when static member of a type accepts System.Func, a corresponding F# lambda can be implicitly converted and accepted. But for let bindings of module, it does not work?

I also used ILSpy to look at the IL generated. For Foo.Invoke1 and Bar.Invoke1, they have the same signature in IL as

```
.method public static 
  string Invoke1 (
    class [mscorlib]System.Func`1<string> action
  ) cil managed
```

So there's no difference on the method itself in IL. For the type, I saw

```
.class public auto ansi abstract sealed Library.Foo
.class public auto ansi serializable Library.Bar
```

So this somehow causes the difference? Anyway, **how to explain the behavior difference between module and type?**

Then I also found that the following does not compile

```
Bar.Invoke4 (5) (fun k -> "") (fun k v -> v)
```

It comes with an error

```
error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type    int    but here has type    unit
```

The difference between Bar.Invoke3 and Bar.Invoke4 is that the former uses tuple form and the latter uses currying form. However, somehow the latter does not compile. In case you are curious

```
Foo.Invoke4 (5) (fun k -> "") (fun k v -> v)
```

does not compile either, it's just the error is different, it's the same as all other "Foo" errors:

```
error FS0002: This function takes too many arguments, or is used in a context where a function is not expected
```

**Any idea on why Bar.Invoke3 works but Bar.Invoke4 does not?**

It's really confusing that when implicit conversion from F# lambda to System.Func can happen and when it cannot happen. What are the explanations for the behaviors described above?

I found some earlier related questions, such as

- [Passing F# function to IEnumerable.Where vs IEnumerable.All](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23256355/passing-f-function-to-ienumerable-where-vs-ienumerable-all)
- [Conversion of lambda expressions to Func](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23234047/conversion-of-lambda-expressions-to-func)

But still could not find a clear explanation on the behaviors.

Any idea?

Note: I tried the above code with F# 4.0

Some context: I found such behaviors when I was trying to explore whether I can write a F# library where some methods takes functors as parameter. Can I write it in a way that it can be used from both F#/C# code. I remember I can use F# lambda with .Net methods that takes System.Func as parameter (e.g. ConcurrentDictonary's AddOrUpdate). So I thought if my functions are using System.Func, it can serve both. **Is this a good/bad assumption**?

Answer (score 4):

In F# type-directed conversions are applied only in invocations of type members (F# spec 8.13.7)

Comment: Thanks! Hmm, I read that section in the answer to one of earlier SO questions, but I didn't realize it's specific to "type" not to "module". What's the reasoning behind this? I sort of expect that the two should behave similarly. Just two different ways of writing types with only static methods. Thus this behavior surprised me. Also, what's the explanation for the difference between Bar.Invoke3 and Bar.Invoke4?

Comment: Type members have lots of OO behavior that module functions don't. E.g. optional params, named params, overloading, etc.  As to the explicit conversion from F# function to Func, that's important for nice interop with .NET libraries (Linq, say), but implicit conversion would be considered bad in a FP context (e.g. modules).

Comment: As to the different behavior of curried members vs tupled members, I would say that members in general should be in tuple form -- that's how people expect classes to work! As soon as you have curried members, then you're in "FP mode" and I would no longer expect to have implicit conversions.   The hybrid FP/OO thing is tricky, but the compiler pulls it off well, I think.